# Fast way to add a number to all cells adjacent a row/column index in a N-dim sparse Numpy Array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

Is there an efficient way to add the same number (int/float) to all cells adjacent to any given [i,j] or [i,j,k] index in a Numpy array without inefficient looping? Just can't seem to find the right slice command.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.zeros((5,5))
arr[0,0] = 2
arr[2,2] = 1
arr
```

Returns

```
Out [1]: array([[ 2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
                [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Looking to accomplish the effect shown below (manually coded to show desired output), but without directly knowing the cell contents or index numbers, other than they are non-zero, and without having to loop over every element in the array.

```
# Add 2 around [0,0]
arr[0:2, 0:2] += 2
arr[0,0] -= 2

# Add 1 around [2,2]
arr[1:4,1:4] += 1
arr[2,2] -= 1
arr

Out [2]: array([[ 2.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                [ 2.,  3.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
                [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
                [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
                [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: The kind of multiple offset summations done in this code for Conway's LIfe is probably as fast as you'll get: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47648106/python-numpy-slicing-indepth-explnation.  My gut feeling is that your alternative would slower unless the array is very sparse.  Either way handling the boundaries can complicate things.

Comment: In order to do your additions for all nonzero points at once, you'll have to use `add.at`, the unbuffered version of `+=`.  Otherwise you won't get `2+1` for `arr[1,1]`.  `add.at` is slower than the buffered code, and doesn't use slicing.

Comment: What's the measure of sparse-ty for your actual use-case? Percentage non-zeros?

Comment: Sparsity (working with 3D arrays) is typically >90% zeros. Thanks @hpaulj for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [85]: arr = np.zeros((5,5))
    ...: arr[0,0] = 2
    ...: arr[2,2] = 1
    ...: 
In [86]: arr
Out[86]: 
array([[ 2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Working with a 0 padded array should be easier:

```
In [87]: arr1 = np.zeros((arr.shape[0]+2, arr.shape[1]+2),arr.dtype)
In [88]: arr1[1:-1,1:-1]=arr
```

Adapting [Python: Numpy slicing indepth explnation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47648106/python-numpy-slicing-indepth-explnation)

```
In [89]: N = np.zeros_like(arr1)
In [90]: Z=arr1
In [91]:     N[1:, 1:] += Z[:-1, :-1]
    ...:     N[1:, :-1] += Z[:-1, 1:]
    ...:     N[:-1, 1:] += Z[1:, :-1]
    ...:     N[:-1, :-1] += Z[1:, 1:]
    ...:     N[:-1, :] += Z[1:, :]
    ...:     N[1:, :] += Z[:-1, :]
    ...:     N[:, :-1] += Z[:, 1:]
    ...:     N[:, 1:] += Z[:, :-1]

In [93]: N += Z
In [94]: N
Out[94]: 
array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
In [95]: N[1:-1, 1:-1]
Out[95]: 
array([[ 2.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Now to try your idea, first iteratively ....

Find the nonzeros:

```
In [124]: idx = np.argwhere(arr1)
In [125]: idx
Out[125]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [3, 3]], dtype=int32)
```

iterate on them:

```
In [126]: N1 = np.zeros_like(arr1)
In [127]: for i in idx:
     ...:     slc = (slice(i[0]-1,i[0]+2), slice(i[1]-1,i[1]+2))
     ...:     N1[slc] += arr1[tuple(i)]
     ...: 
In [128]: N1[1:-1,1:-1]
Out[128]: 
array([[ 2.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Same iteration but with `np.add.at`:

```
In [132]: N1 = np.zeros_like(arr1)
In [133]: for i in idx:
     ...:     slc = (slice(i[0]-1,i[0]+2), slice(i[1]-1,i[1]+2))
     ...:     np.add.at(N1, slc, arr1[tuple(i)])
```

Next step would be to consolidate those `slc` into one whole, so the `np.add.at` can be done once.  A step towards that is to expand the slices with `np.ix_`:

```
In [143]: for i in idx:
     ...:     slc = (slice(i[0]-1,i[0]+2), slice(i[1]-1,i[1]+2))
     ...:     ii = np.ix_(np.r_[slc[0]],np.r_[slc[1]])
     ...:     np.add.at(N1,ii, arr1[tuple(i)])
     ...:     print(ii)
     ...:     
     ...: 
(array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]]), array([[0, 1, 2]]))
(array([[2],
       [3],
       [4]]), array([[2, 3, 4]]))
```

( to be continued )

I was thinking I could concatenate these, to make `[0,1,2,2,3,4]` etc.  But that's not going to work.  I need to generate the `mgrid` arrays, and concatenate those.

```
In [159]: slc=[np.mgrid[(slice(i[0]-1,i[0]+2), slice(i[1]-1,i[1]+2))] for i in idx]
In [160]: slc = tuple(np.hstack(slc))
In [161]: N2 = np.zeros_like(arr1)
In [162]: np.add.at(N2, slc,1)
In [163]: N2[1:-1,1:-1]
Out[163]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

This is close.  I'm adding 1 at each point rather than the corresponding `arr` value.  I need to broadcast those points to the right shape.

This still has an iteration over the nonzero points, but I can imagine generating that idx array with broadcasted addition.

I need to add these:

```
In [182]: slc1 = np.mgrid[slice(-1,2), slice(-1,2)]
In [183]: slc1
Out[183]: 
array([[[-1, -1, -1],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 1,  1,  1]],

       [[-1,  0,  1],
        [-1,  0,  1],
        [-1,  0,  1]]])
In [177]: idx
Out[177]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [3, 3]], dtype=int32)
```

in such as way as to produce:

```
In [179]: slc=[np.mgrid[(slice(i[0]-1,i[0]+2), slice(i[1]-1,i[1]+2))] for i in idx]
In [180]: slc=np.hstack(slc)  # np.concatenate(slc, axis=1)
In [181]: slc
Out[181]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4]]])
```

This does it (but can I do more directly?)

```
In [228]: slc2 = idx.T[:,:,None,None]+slc1[:,None,:,:]
In [229]: np.concatenate(list(slc2.transpose(1,0,2,3)),1)
Out[229]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4]]])
```

Replicating the nonzero values to the matching shape:

```
In [288]: pts = arr1[tuple(idx.T)]
In [289]: pts
Out[289]: array([ 2.,  1.])
In [290]: pts1 = pts.repeat(3)[:,None].repeat(3,axis=1)
In [291]: pts1
Out[291]: 
array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
In [292]: np.add.at(N2,tuple(Out[229]), pts1)
```

`pts1 = pts.repeat(3)[:,None]` without the last repeat also works (because of broadcasting).

So this can all be packed into a couple of functions and timed on some realistic size arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the really in-depth solution. Still working through it, but even the indexing solution works great so far as I can see for a couple examples I've tried