# Numpy - even more position-based array modification

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masked-array

I have a large 2-dimensional numpy array, with every value being a 0 or a 1. I'd like to create a function which takes this array as an input, and returns a new array of the same size in which each element is based on the elements above, below and to either side. The returned array should have 0's stay 0, and each 1 will get +1 if there is a 1 to the north, +2 for a 1 to the right, +4 for a 1 below and +8 for a 1 to the left. These all stack, so a 1 surrounded by 1's should end up as a 17. Diagonals do not matter. This might also be faster with explicit bitwise operations (with 4 bits, each bit corresponding to a direction and whether there is a 1 or 0 in it).

I would like this operation to be done as quickly as possible. I played around with a for loop but it is too slow, and I don't understand masking in numpy well enough to use that.

Comment: Preamble, this sounds like an assignment. Can you share your attempt?

Comment: Sounds like a variation on Conway's Life game.  Here's a numpy explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47648106/python-numpy-slicing-indepth-explnation

Comment: How exactly do you get `17`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can help. I start copying the original matrix, then add the contribution from each direction. For example if I have to add the contribute of the elements on the right, they may modify all the columns but the last one, thus I can write `result[:,:-1] += m[:,1:]`. The last multiplication for `m` ensures that the starting value of each cell to modify was one and not zero, as you required.

```py
import numpy as np

def f(m):
    result = np.copy(m)
    # propagation from the four directions
    result[1:,:] += m[:-1,:]  # north
    result[:,:-1] += 2 * m[:,1:]  # est
    result[:-1,:] += 4 * m[1:,:]  # sud
    result[:,1:] += 8 * m[:,:-1]  # west
    return result * m
```

Comment: @Preamble, does it solve your problem? This seems a very efficient solution. I evaluated it with %timeit on 100x100 matrices and it worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

The operation you describe can be expressed as linear convolution followed by zeroing out the spots that were zero before:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import signal
>>> 
>>> kernel = np.array([[0,1,0], [8,1,2], [0,4,0]])[::-1, ::-1]
>>> 
>>> pattern = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 10))
>>> 
>>> pattern
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
>>> 
>>> pattern * signal.convolve(pattern, kernel, 'same')
array([[ 0,  3, 15, 11, 15, 11,  9,  0,  3,  9],
       [ 1,  0,  2,  0,  6,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  3, 12, 13,  0,  1,  0,  1],
       [ 1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  8, 13,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  5,  0,  3, 11, 16, 12, 15, 15,  9],
       [ 0,  2,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  4, 14,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  3,  9,  0,  5,  0,  6,  0],
       [ 0,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  6,  0],
       [ 0,  8, 11, 13,  0,  5,  0,  7, 10,  0],
       [ 0,  2,  0,  4, 11, 10,  0,  2,  0,  0]])
```